# Quotes without backslash in subprocess command line in python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

I'm trying to use ffmpeg from python.  The command I need to execute is:

```
ffmpeg -i test_file-1kB.mp4 -i test_file.mp4 -filter_complex psnr="stats_file=test_file.mp4-1kB.psnr" -f null -
```

However, my output that is getting passed to subprocess looks like it is escaping the double quotes with backslashes like so:

```
In[1]: print(subprocess.list2cmdline(psnr_args))
ffmpeg -i test_file-1kB.mp4 -i test_file.mp4 -filter_complex psnr=\"stats_file=test_file.mp4-1kB.psnr\" -f null -
```

To use subprocess, I build my command line arguments one at a time into a list and then pass the list to subprocess.

```
    psnr_args = []
    psnr_args.append("ffmpeg")

    #add first input, the encoded video
    psnr_args.append("-i")
    psnr_args.append(full_output_file_name)

    #add second input, the original video
    psnr_args.append("-i")
    psnr_args.append(video_file)

    #Setup the psnr log file
    psnr_args.append("-filter_complex")
    psnr_args.append('psnr="stats_file=%s.psnr"' % vstats_abs_filename )

    #Output the video to null
    psnr_args.append("-f")
    psnr_args.append("null")
    psnr_args.append("-")
    print(subprocess.list2cmdline(psnr_args))
    run_info_psnr = subprocess.run(psnr_args, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: The quotes are instructions **to the shell**, not to ffmpeg. If you don't have a shell, you shouldn't have literal quotes. Just leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

After more fiddling, I found a solution that works in this case but may not work in all cases.  If I use double quotes as the outer quotes and the single quotes as the inner quotes, the output to subprocess uses a single quote at the same location with no backslash.  This is acceptable for ffmpeg.  However, for others where double quotes are the only solution, it won't be a fix.

```
psnr_args.append("psnr='stats_file=%s.psnr'" % vstats_abs_filename )
```

Output to subprocess looks like this:

```
In[1]: print(subprocess.list2cmdline(psnr_args))
ffmpeg -i test_file-1kB.mp4 -i test_file.mp4 -filter_complex psnr='stats_file=test_file.mp4-1kB.psnr' -f null -
```

Comment: `list2cmdline` is a Windows-ism. If you want to convert a list to a command line in a way that's meaningful on Unix-family systems, use `' '.join(pipes.quote(x) for x in psnr_args)` in Python 2, or the same with `shlex.quote` substituted for `pipes.quote` in Python 3.

Comment: simple quotes have no particular meaning in windows.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, (1) true. (2) was that directed at me?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy nope. I know you know :)

Answer (score 1):

In shell, the argument:

```
psnr="stats_file=test_file.mp4-1kB.psnr"
```

Is **absolutely identical to**:

```
psnr=stats_file=test_file.mp4-1kB.psnr
```

The quotes are removed during the shell's own processing. They are **not** part of the command passed to `ffmpeg`, which doesn't expect or understand them. Because you're directly telling the Python subprocess module to invoke a literal argument vector, there's no shell involved, so shell syntax shouldn't be present.

Answer (score 0):

This has something to do with ffmpeg AV filter chain syntax too. You need to run the command like `xxxx -filter_complex "psnr='stats.txt'" xxxx`. To get this, you should ensure the double quote that encapsulate the filter chain reaches inside. subproces expects a flat list as the first argument, where the command is the first entry. So `['ffmpeg', '-i', "t1.mp4", "-filter_compelx", '"psnr=\'stats.txt\'"', .... and so on ]`.